# Responsive horizontal carousel for links - bootstrap-mvc

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC project where I use bootsrap.

I need a horizontal menu of links that slides that slides with the arrows on right and left (a carousel but not for images for links).

To be more specific: it needs to be responsive, showing as many items as it can fit to screen of the device,  it needs to take the string length into consideration because the links that will be displayed in the menu is managed by users. 
I have tried using bootstrap carousel; that doesnt show more than one item at a time; I have checked flexisel, and I managed to create the menu, but this solution is not checking the string length, so if a user adds long  text to one of the options, it breaks.

Anybody knows a good solution, library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried responsive carousel?

Here is the link to for it: [Responsive Carousel](https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel)

With that you can change what you see when viewport width is changed.